# Backtracking exercise graph color in C

Tags: c, graph, colors, backtracking

Can someone explain me the approach that I've to use to solve this type of exercise?

I've a map with 5 areas, and I've 4 colours: Green, Red, Yellow and Blue.

[image: Image of the 5 areas]

I've to colour the areas with this 4 colours (adjacent areas may NOT have same colour)

I've to show on stdout all the possible solutions

[image: Image of possible solution]

I had thought about using 2 arrays: 1 for the areas, and 1 for the colours, and try all the possible permutations. But how can I set the adjacent constraint in the array? Thanks.

Comment: What is your data structure for representing the `graph`?

Comment: I don't have a proper data structure I can use array, matrix, ecc.. whatever I want. I've to show on stdout the possible solutions (console project)

Comment: You can present `graph` as a `matrix` of the connections between nodes. Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solve this problem is using two matrices:
1.Matrix for adjacency
2.Matrix for coloring

**Approach:**

1. Iterate through all the blocks(areas) with a `nested loop` and take input 1 if two areas are adjacent else take input 0. Store these values in your matrix corresponding to the areas
   i.e:

   `if(input==1)
   adjacency[i][j]==adjacency[j][i]==1
   else
   adjacency[i][j]==adjacency[j][i]==0`

   This way you will have a matrix of elements showing the adjacency of each of them.
2. Then create an empty matrix of same size for coloring. Iterate through this matrix diagonally (i.e. `color[i][i]`), assigning a color (in order) to the areas and then checking the adjacency matrix for adjacent areas.
    
   If the areas are adjacent (i.e. `adjacency[i][j]==1`), then check the adjacent area's color (i.e. `color[j][j]`). If its same (i.e. `color[i][i]==color[j][j]`), then change your color to the next color and repeat the process again, till all of the areas are assigned a color.

**NOTE:** Neither the only way to solve it nor can I say it's the most effective way, you can work out a better logic that will have lower time and space complexities.